# Method with two generic collections of same class

Tags: java, generics

I would like to implement the following method, but I'm uncertain how to do this in Java generics.

This is what I would like to have:

```
public <C extends Collection> C<DomainDTO> transform(C<DomainModel> arg);
```

This is what compiles, but doesn't ensure A and B are of the same class that extends Collection:

```
public <A extends Collection<DomainDTO>, B extends Collection<DomainModel>> A transform(B arg);
```

Thanks for any ideas, or just confirmation that it's impossible.

EDIT:
I'll try to word this better, since it seems people confuse what I'm looking for. The use case here is (should be) simple. I need a method to populate a Collection of DTOs from a Collection of models. Right now I have many methods for different Collections, but I would prefer to have one generic method that takes any Collection as the parameter, and returns the DTOs in a Collection of the same class.

Comment: Aren't you just looking for something like: `public static <F, T> List<T> transform(List<F> fromList);`? If so, Google Guava already has it: http://docs.guava-libraries.googlecode.com/git/javadoc/com/google/common/collect/Lists.html

Comment: @RobbyCornelissen thanks, but not quite. The two classes contained in the collections are fixed, but the type of the collection should remain open.

Comment: I'm curious if Java's generics system is expressive enough for this... I know how to have input/output be the same collection type with the same contents, but I'm not sure if you can specify the same collection type with *different* contents.

Comment: I think the only way to guarantee the same collection type (with different element types) is to use something like: `public <C extends Collection<?>> C convert( final C collection )` but then that doesn't include the element types. This is probably the reason I've previously seen APIs define multiple methods for this, like: `public List<A> convert( final List<B> collection )` and `public Set<A> convert( final Set<B> collection )`

Comment: Thanks @DanTemple , you are on the same page with me! If no one posts a generic solution in a while, I'll accept your answer of keeping different methods.

Comment: What you're asking for is a little complicated for the grammar. I agree with @DanTemple that you would greatly benefit from simplifying what you're doing. Pick one kind of Collection and stick to it, create overloads or program to the interface.

Answer (score 0):

Specify the type of the collection *parameter*, not the collection itself:

```
public <T> Collection<T> transform(Collection<T> arg);
```

---

If the question is asking for both the element type *and* the *collection* type to be the same:

```
public <T, C extends Collection<T>> C transform(C arg);
```

Comment: Doesn't this have the same problem as the OP has stated? `doesn't ensure A and B are of the same class that extends Collection` Here we could transform a Set<T> into a List<T>, which isn't what the OP wants.

Comment: The parameter of the Collection is fixed. What I'd need is to be able to call the method with List<Class1> and get List<Class2>, or Set<Class1> and get Set<Class2> etc. Thanks anyway!

Comment: @Bohemian It seems that there could be two *different* `T`s... As in the generic parameter for the input and return type are different.

Comment: Think of it like this: We want a single method to convert a collection of Strings to a Collection of Integers. If the Collection of strings is a Set, then the method should return a Set of Integers, but if the Collection of Strings is a List, then the *same* method should return a List of Integers. The two element types in the collections are fixed (String & Integer) but the type of the collection is the generic part. Personally I don't think it's possible without something like: `public <C extends Collection<?>> C convert( final C collection )` but then the element types aren't included.

Answer (score 0):

> EDIT: The question originally was ambiguous, to say the least. My proposed solution is not applicable to the edited question. However, the recommendation I made is still valid:

I wonder how you would like to implement this **without** using `newInstance` etc. You have to create a new instance of an unknown type...

You might alternatively consider a signature [...] where the caller can pass the target collection manually, and type safety is still maintained

> EDIT: Updated code for the updated question:

The most generic form that I could imagine for this is sketched below.

```
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.Arrays;
import java.util.Collection;
import java.util.HashSet;
import java.util.List;
import java.util.Set;

public class SomeCollectionTest
{
    static interface Converter<S, T>
    {
        T convert(S s);
    }
    static class Parser implements Converter<String, Integer>
    {
        @Override
        public Integer convert(String s)
        {
            return Integer.parseInt(s);
        }
    }

    public static void main(String[] args)
    {
        Collection<String> input = Arrays.asList("0","1","2","3");
        List<String> listIn = new ArrayList<String>(input);
        Set<String> setIn = new HashSet<String>(input);
        Parser p = new Parser();

        List<Integer> listOutA  = convert(listIn, new ArrayList<Integer>(), p);
        List<Integer> listOutB  = convert(setIn,  new ArrayList<Integer>(), p);
        //List<Integer> noListOut = convert(listIn, new HashSet<Integer>(), p);
        Set<Integer> setOutA = convert(setIn, new HashSet<Integer>(), p);
        Set<Integer> setOutB = convert(setIn, new HashSet<Integer>(), p);
        //Set<Integer> noSetOut = convert(listIn, new ArrayList<Integer>(), p);

        System.out.println(listOutA);
        System.out.println(setOutA);
    }

    private static <S, T, C extends Collection<? super T>> C convert(
        Iterable<? extends S> input, C output, Converter<S, T> converter)
    {
        for (S s : input)
        {
            output.add(converter.convert(s));
        }
        return output;
    }
}
```

And by the way: I'd even consider it as being **advantageous** to have the possibility to convert, for example, a `Collection<DomainDTO>` into a `List<DomainModel>` - particularly when you don't **know** the exact type of the first collection. Otherwise, you'd have to do this in two steps:

```
Collection<DTO> collectionOfDto = read();
Collection<DomainModel> dm = convert(dto); // Only receive a collection here...

// Sigh, I need a list. Maybe it already IS a list, but
// I don't know it. So I have to do this:
List<DomainModel> list = new ArrayList<DomainModel>(dm);
```